# How do I live transcode a wmv file for playback in html5 player?

Tags: html, ffmpeg, html5-video, video.js

I've been working at this for quite awhile and still haven't found a solution that works. I need a way to **live convert** (transcode) a .wmv file for playback in a html5 web player.

I have a linux server (Apache) setup to stream video files through an html5 web player (Video.js) designed for Chrome and Firefox browsers. The file types I am dealing with are .mp4 (H.264), .mkv, and .wmv. The good news for me is that I can deal with mp4 and mkv natively, however I can't play wmv. Also, I have to deal with a lot of files, change periodically, and **can be quite large**.

After doing a lot of research and reading many times how you **can't** stream wmv directly, I came to the realization that I had two options. Either convert the file to a supported format or live transcode a file for use in the web player. Due to the amount of files and their size (and periodically changing) converting the file is simply not feasible. So I am stuck with live streaming/transcoding. I figured ffmpeg would be the way to go, but I have yet to figure out how to get ffmpeg to live stream into the html5 player.

So how do I take an existing .wmv file and live stream it in an html5 player?

The things I've tried so far:

Tried creating a m3u8 playlist and hoping it would magically work.

```
ffmpeg -i "hello.wmv" -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -f ssegment -hls_flags delete_segments -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_type hls -segment_list_size 10 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 10 out_%6d.ts
```

Simply copying to mp4 and streaming while ffmpeg still progressing. Obviously didn't work.

```
ffmpeg -i "hello.wmv"  -vcodec copy video.mp4
```

Converting to webm format and streaming webm while ffmpeg still progressing. This actually did show the video for a few seconds in the html player:

```
ffmpeg -i "hello.wmv" -codec:a libvorbis -codec:v libvpx -b:a 128k -b:v 1200k video.webm
```

Ffmpeg is not required to be used (was thinking of vlc as well), the html5 player is required. Completely converting then streaming isn't a viable option because file sizes can be too large and change periodically. What command/program can I use to stream the file for playback in the html player?

Comment: are multiple people going to view the file, or just one (if you're transcoding multiple files concurrently then you're going to hit CPU limits). I guess in theory you could create an HLS stream from the source and display that in the browser

Comment: @ Offbeatmammal At the moment, just one. Will deal with multiple users at a different time. As you said, HLS was a good idea (tried with ffmpeg in first example), however it seems that the video keeps trying to start from the beginning when moving to the next file. Not sure if it is a code issue or a browser issue. HLS is the closest so far to getting what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a LOT of different ways, I finally came up with a workable solution. Posting here for anyone that may come across it in the future. The solution I ended up with is using HLS (live stream) which segments the file. Using the output .m3u8 file I then used it in video tag for my html5 player.

The following is what I used in ffmpeg. Note that I set the preset to ultrafast (because libx264 was very slow by what I've seen). I'm sure there are more efficient parameters to use with ffmpeg and I will definitely continue to do more testing, but this is confirmed as working:

```
ffmpeg -i "hello.wmv" -preset ultrafast -c:v libx264 -f ssegment -hls_flags delete_segments -segment_list play_file.m3u8 -segment_list_type hls -segment_list_size 0 out_%6d.ts
```

In the html video tag, simply use:

```
 <source src="play_file.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
```

Note for anyone who may come across this in the future: if you run into "file not supported error" when using the type x-mpegURL, then something is wrong with your source js. Make sure to have the hls.js (in my case videojs-contrib-hls.js) or it will throw the error. Took me a long time to figure out it wasn't the browser but the html js that was actually the issue.

I think this solution should work for nearly any video type that ffmpeg supports. Simply change around the input file and maybe mess around with the codecs if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do random seeking to a time fragment before it is transcoded?